# Play Framework Scala Templates looping through two lists comparing items

Tags: scala, for-loop, if-statement, playframework, html-table

I'm trying to compare two lists by using only scala templates from play framework. My goal is to show all items `listA` in a table and then find out if `listA` has objects containing the same values as in `listB` to change the appearence of the duplicated items.

So let's assume `a.id` has an equivalent `b.id`, then i want `a.id` to appear in the list but crossed-out.

Example Input: `listA` has 5 objects with the attributes `name` and `id`. `listB` has 2 objects with the attributes `id` and `xxx`.

Desired Output: I want to display all items from `listA` (using the first scala @for loop), but if the `id` already exists in `listB`, i want the item to be <s>crossed out</s> in my table.

This is what i got so far:

```
 <tbody>
        @for(a <- aList){
            @for(b <- bList){
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Key</th>
                       <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 @if(a.id == b.id){
                    <tr>
                        <td><s>@a.id</s></td>
                        <td><s>@a.name</s></td>
                    </tr>
                    } else { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>@a.id</td>
                        <td>@a.name</td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                }
             } </tbody>
```

So far the code works, but now every element from `listA` appears as many times as the second loop goes through, which absolutely makes sense, but how can i prevent that?

Comment: Could you give an example of input/output, so we can be sure of what you actually want?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I updated my question - i hope that explains it better now. Sorry! Thank you in advance if you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do this in Scala code, rather than inside the template.

What you want is `listA` with a Boolean for each element telling you if it's in `listB`. Here's a simple way to do this:

```
val listAWithBool = listA.map(a => (a,  listB.map(_.id).contains(a.id)))
```

Then, in your for loop, you can do

```
@for((a,inB) <- listAWithBool){
  @if(inB){
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you're using Play Java, most of what I wrote previously will be hard to put in code, since it's functional programming. A possible solution is to put all that in your template, which allows scala code; just put this at the top of your template (under the list of parameters):

```
@listAWithBool = @{
  listA.map(a => (a,  listB.map(_.id).contains(a.id)))
}
```

Now to explain the weird `for((a, inB) <- listAWithBool)` syntax: just as `for(a <- listA)` means "extract all values from my list and do the following with each of them, giving it the name `a`", this now means "extract all pairs of values from my list and do the following with each of them, giving name `a` and `inB` to its two elements.

Remember that we have built `listAWithBool` to be a list of pairs (as return type of the lambda) of type `List[A, Boolean]`, so the compiler will be able to understand that `a` is of type `A` and `inB` is of type `Boolean`.

Comment: This seems to be the solution that will work for me! Thanks a lot. I got Java code running behind but the syntax looks like to be the same as using lambda expressions in java, which i am familiar with. Only thing i don't really understand is the syntax in the @for loop. What does it mean to have 2 parameters there?  `(a,inB)`

Comment: Sorry for the double comment - another thing that i'm not a 100% sure about. Do i have to add a boolean attribute to the type of class that my list is of? The problem is i'm getting the data from an existing data source and i want to avoid changing the existing data model. But if there's no work around i have to change it anyways...

Comment: I'm not sure your java lists have `map` and `contains` method, which could make it harder to write the lambda. Moreover, pairs `(a, b)` are also less natural to work with in java... which is a shame because this is the workaround for avoiding to add the boolean parameter to your class.

Comment: As a non Scala developer the syntax is still a bit difficult to understand, but you did your best at explaining everything and the code works like a charm! Thank you so much, you helped me a lot and saved me a huge amount of time.

Comment: If you're starting to realise that collections are poorly handled in Java, you're most welcome to try and learn scala! You just need to get the hang of it, and the first coursera course on it already gives you a good understanding of how it works, and why it's so powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var valueA= document.getElementById(@a.id);

var valueB= document.getElementById(@b.id);
@if(valueA == valueB){

}
```

Or 
You can use

```
if(valueA.contains(valueB)){

}
```